# How can the LEFT JOIN return more results than the unjoined query?

Tags: join

Consider the following queries:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM list l WHERE l.source='blink';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     3372 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM list l LEFT JOIN cardinal c ON l.id=c.id WHERE c.resolution IN ('Left','Right','Up') AND l.source='blink';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     5116 |
+----------+
1 row in set (2.47 sec)
```

There were no `INSERT` or other queries run on the database between these two queries running. **The second query seems *more restrictive* than the first query, so how could it return more rows?** Note that the `list` table has over 2 million rows, and the `cardinal` table has about half a million rows.

**EDIT:** Adding `EXPLAIN` output:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) FROM list l LEFT JOIN cardinal c ON l.id=c.id WHERE c.resolution IN ('Left','Right','Up') AND l.source='blink';
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys     | key     | key_len | ref         | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+-------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ALL    | NULL              | NULL    | NULL    | NULL        | 536258 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | l     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,id,source | PRIMARY | 8       | direct.c.id |      1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+-------------+--------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from list;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  2165664 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.32 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from cardinal;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   537007 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.23 sec)
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join

Comment: Thank you Phil, but the `WHERE` clause of `l.source='blink'` still applies to the left table in the second query.

Comment: Testing with `INNER JOIN` gives the same result of `5116`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not awake yet and the answer is obvious. It's a 1<>many relationship between the two tables

Comment: I'm brewing coffee :) I'm not seeing how adding more restrictions _increases_ the results size. Both queries are restricted to `WHERE l.source='blink'`. The second query is _additionally_ restricted to `WHERE c.resolution IN ('Left','Right','Up')`. I don't think that the `JOIN` will _add_ records as it is a LEFT or INNER JOIN (I tried both, same result).

Comment: Each row in the first table may match more than one row in the second table. You can check this with `SELECT l.id,count(*) 
FROM list l 
LEFT JOIN cardinal c ON l.id=c.id
WHERE c.resolution IN ('Left','Right','Up') AND l.source='blink'
group by l.id
having count(*)>1;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each row in the first table may match more than one row in the second table.

You can check this with:

```
SELECT l.id,count(*) 
FROM list l 
LEFT JOIN cardinal c ON l.id=c.id 
WHERE c.resolution IN ('Left','Right','Up') AND l.source='blink' 
group by l.id 
having count(*)>1;
```

A little demo is on SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba071/3).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not linked to you adding restrictions but with the JOIN.

When a row from table `l` has for instance 3 corresponding rows in `c`, three rows would be added to the result set.