# Select records in one table but not in another, when the second table is not matching on primary key

Tags: mysql, join, select

I have two tables from which I need only the results that appear in one table (`list`) which do not appear in the second table (`cardinal`). The `list` table's primary key is `sku`, and the table has a vestige `id` column (which is actually unused in the application at the moment). The `cardinal` table's primary key is `id`. The column which should join the tables is `sku`. These are the tables (relevant fields only, there are other fields that I didn't paste here):

```
mysql> describe list;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name            | varchar(63)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sku             | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> describe cardinal;
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| sku              | bigint(20)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here are the amount of records in each table:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM list;
+----------+
|  2677513 |
+----------+

mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM cardinal;
+----------+
|   970924 |
+----------+
```

Every record in the `cardinal` table has a valid entry for the `sku` column, and all of those valid entries do exist in the `list` table. [There do exist some dupes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54701/how-can-the-left-join-return-more-results-than-the-unjoined-query) for `sku` in the `cardinal` table.

**I need all the records in the `list` table which do not have a corresponding entry in the `cardinal` table.** However, all the methods that I'm trying are returning either all the records from the `list` table, or no records at all!

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM list l LEFT JOIN cardinal c ON c.id=null;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  2677513 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.49 sec)

mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM list l LEFT OUTER JOIN cardinal c ON l.sku=c.sku where c.id=null;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
```

The first query obviously doesn't know to match on the `sku` column. But the second one looks like it should work [based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153557/mysql-select-fields-in-one-table-that-are-not-in-another-table) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another) [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767565/mysql-select-rows-from-a-table-that-are-not-in-another) [that I've](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767565/mysql-select-rows-from-a-table-that-are-not-in-another) [seen online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596073/select-from-one-table-where-not-in-another).

**I expect about 1700000 - 2000000 rows to be returned.** But certainly not 0 or the full table. How should I word the query? This is MySQL 5.5.33 running in Amazon RDS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL, in fact, all SQL products really barf at

```
c.id=NULL
```

It causes confusion. You really mean

```
c.id IS NULL
```

You need to change it to

```
SELECT count(*) FROM list l LEFT OUTER JOIN cardinal c ON l.sku=c.sku where c.id is null;
```

Give it a Try !!!

## ABOUT YOUR QUESTION

Your first query

```
SELECT count(*) FROM list l LEFT JOIN cardinal c ON c.id=null;
```

resembles a natural join where nothing matches on the cardinal table, so the count `2677513` is correct.

Your second query

```
SELECT count(*) FROM list l LEFT OUTER JOIN cardinal c ON l.sku=c.sku where c.id=null;
```

is little more explicit, but the `c.id=null` makes it fail, thus getting 0 as a count.

Comment: You are my hero! When you ever get to Beersheba there is a cold beer waiting for you!